# Asymmetric sidescrolloff aka horizontal scrolling should do the right thing in vim

Tags: vim

I've been very happy with setting `scrolloff=999` in my .vimrc - this keeps the cursor always in the center of the screen, allowing me to just think about moving the cursor and repurposing all the vertical scrolling keybindings.

I'd like horizontal scrolling to work automatically too (when `nowrap` is set), and recently discovered `sidescrolloff`, but setting this to a high value doesn't result in a nice experience - the beginning of the line frequently disappears from the screen when editing the end of the line.

Is there a way to get vim to keep the cursor at least `n` characters from the right edge of the screen while eagerly returning the scroll to the far left whenever possible?

Schematically,

`horizontalScrollPos = max(cursorPos + n - screenWidth, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

It appears there is no option shipped with vim which allows you to do what you want.  However, it can be done with some vim wizardry *(or hackery)*.

```
" Only scroll once to the side when you hit the side of the screen.
" (or the padding specified in sidescrolloff)
set sidescroll=1
" This sets the padding on the right side of the screen.
set sidescrolloff=4

" Make a script-local function for use in a later autocommand.  It
" is not made global because nothing else should need to use it.
function s:FixScroll()
    " Check if wrap is set, and if it is, return from the function.
    " This is so that the entire function isn't run if wrap is on.
    if &wrap
        return 0
    " This if statement checks if the horizontal scroll amount is
    " 0, and returns from the function if it is.  This way
    " the rest of the function isn't run when unnecessary.
    elseif col(".") - wincol() - &fdc + &number * &numberwidth ==# 0
        return 0
    endif

    " Figure out which column that the cursor needs to be in when
    " scrolling.  'sidescrolloff` is the option set earlier, or
    " the padding from the right side of the screen.
    let l:targetcol = winwidth(0) - &sidescrolloff

    " This checks to see if the cursor is to the left of the target
    " column.  
    if wincol() < l:targetcol
        " Figure out how far to scroll to the left to get the
        " cursor in the target column.
        let l:move_amount = l:targetcol - wincol()
        " Use 'zh' to scroll to the left by the specified amount
        " using the exe command.
        exe 'normal! ' . l:move_amount . 'zh'
    endif
endfunction

" Run the local fixscroll function every time the cursor is moved in
" normal or insert mode.
autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * call <SID>FixScroll()
```

Relevant help topics:

```
:help 'sidescrolloff'
:help 'sidescroll'
:help col()
:help wincol()
:help winwidth()
:help zh
:help zl
:help autocmd-groups-abc
```

Comment: It seems that `sidescrolloff={pad}` combined with `sidescrolloff=1` allows for part of what you want, and I will update my answer with a more efficient solution once I figure this out.